# How to use functions from different C++ projects in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include, unresolved-external, multiple-projects

I would like to build two C++ projects in the same solution in Visual Studio 2010 that can interact with each other. I have created a solution under directory `C:\Users\me\Desktop\SolutionDir`. The two projects have been created respectively under `C:\Users\me\Desktop\SolutionDir\FirstProject` and `C:\Users\me\Desktop\SolutionDir\SecondProject`.

My first project contains two files, a header `function.h` and a cpp file `function.cpp`

#### function.h

```cpp
#pragma once
void print_stuff();
```

#### function.cpp

```cpp
#include "function.h"
#include <iostream>

void print_stuff() {
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

My second project contains the main file `main.cpp`

#### main.cpp

```cpp
#include "FirstProject\function.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    print_stuff();

    int stop;
    std::cin >> stop;
    return 0;
}
```

I added the directory `C:\Users\me\Desktop\SolutionDir\` in my SecondProject `Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories`. I still get the classical error : `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol` when calling the function `print_stuff()`.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try building the first project as a Static Library in Project Properties/Configuration Properties/General/Configuration Type.

Then in your project properties for the second project, you'll need to change two things:

1. In Linker/General, you might need to add to "Additional Library Directories" the folder where the first project's `.lib` is built.
2. In Linker/Input, you will need to add to Additional Dependencies the name of the `.lib` file like `FirstProject.lib` or whatever its name is.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I totally forgot to specify that FirstProject should be a static library. It is now working !

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to export the functions using `_declspec(dllexport)` and import them in the project that calls the functions with `_declspec(dllimport)`.

This duality is usually achieved with a macro:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef FIRST_PROJECT_BUILD
#define IMPEXP _declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define IMPEXP _declspec(dllimport)
#endif

IMPEXP void print_stuff();
```

In the configuration of your first project, you add `FIRST_PROJECT_BUILD` to your preprocessor directives. That way, when you compile first project, you tell the compiler the function is to be exported. However, when you include the file in a different project, that doesn't have `FIRST_PROJECT_BUILD` defined, you tell the compiler the function is implemented in a different library and should be imported.

Also, besides adding the extra include paths, you need to add the generated `.lib` files from the projects implementing the functions to the `Extra dependencies` tab in the Liner settings of your project configuration.

Comment: This is assuming the first project is a `.dll`

Comment: I gathered that the OP doesn't know about DLLs.  You won't be able to tell them everything they need to know,but a link or something might get them on their way.

Comment: @ChrisA. why? Can't you dynamically load an exe? :)

Comment: I was under the impression that `_declspec(dllexport)` only should be used when exporting from a `.dll`. Will it also work if the first project is a static library?

Comment: @ChrisA. IDK if it's needed for a static lib, but I don't see why it won't work.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it doesn't hurt in the case of a static library.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a realPath for you include directory !
Like for your FirstProject include "./../"
And the same include dir for your second Project like that you can move or copy your directory SolutionDir and it will always work !

For your unresolved linked you have to add the function.cpp and function.h in your First and Second Project 
You can place it in SolutionDir!
Like that You always have two files for your first and second project instead of four !

Hope it helps !