# Error LNK2019 when try to use function from namespace

Tags: c++, visual-c++, namespaces, compiler-errors

I'm writing some utils functions to my project. I got a strange LNK2019 error when I tried to use some functions from nested namespace. I tried to search in google and in stackoverflow but I didn't get something to help me.

### My files

Header file `X.h`:

```
#pragma once

namespace A {
    namespace B {
        /**
         * A função recebe edValue e devolve em ponto flutuante
         * o inteiro mais próximo de edValue.
         * 
         * Método usado: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_rounding#Round_half_up
         *
         * @param edValue valor que será arredondado.
         * @return o inteiro mais próximo à edValue (em ponto flutuante).
         */
        double round(double edValue);
    }
}
```

CPP file `X.cpp`

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "X.h"
#include <cmath>

double A::B::round(double edValue)
{
    return floor(edValue + 0.5);
}
```

### Error message

`7>D.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl A::B::round(double)" (?round@A@B@@YANN@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall`

## Edit (solution to my problem)

My files `X.{h,cpp}` are in project A and Im using those functions in project B. If I use `__declspec(dllexport)` in my function's prototype I can use those functions in project B, cause it uses A like DLL. I got this tip in [How to use functions from different C++ projects in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438770/how-to-use-functions-from-different-c-projects-in-visual-studio-2010) (replied by @Luchian Grigore) and [Visual studio: question about linking functions between two projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094312/visual-studio-question-about-linking-functions-between-two-projects) (replied by @dascandy).

Comment: Are you linking `X.obj` into whatever binary that you're linking `D.obj` into?

Comment: they are in differents projects in my visual studio solution. In my D property pages > Common Properties > Framework and References I have reference to project where I create those namespaces.

Comment: Because they are in different projects you have to provide full path to included file, not just short "X.h". When you use "some file name" - compiler looks for given file in folder of current project

Comment: When I move all my implementation to `X.h` I can compile.

Comment: Is the project that compiles `X.cpp` is a static library? Does the type of "reference" that you've selected imply linking against the output of the referent project?

Answer (score 0):

If the code for the function is in a different project you must compile it to a static or dynamic library and then add the library to the calling project in the project options under Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies (for MS Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

- Specify the path of the library you are using under Linker > General > Additional Dependencies + - - Specify which library you are using under Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies